# Basic Mapping Question

Tags: solidity, mapping

Very basic question but would appreciate any help understanding this. I don't quite understand the logic behind the += operator within the below mapping. Please see below code

```
function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function sendMoney() public payable {
        balanceReceived[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
```

How can you logically add and assign and have - balanceReceived [msg.sender] = balanceReceived [msg.sender] + msg.value?

I am sure I am looking at this the wrong way but the balanceRecieved [msg.sender] is a address so how can you add that to a uint value of msg.value?

Comment: we need to see the mapping definition

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the mapping definition I'd guess it's something like

```
mapping(address => uint) balanceReceived;
```

that means `balanceReceived[msg.sender]` is not an address, it's what an address is mapped to, which is a uint

Comment: Hi Sola. Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for that and yes you were correct - that was the mapping definition. Another question - From what I understand the 
` balanceReceived[msg.sender] ` accesses the mapping of the msg.sender address to the uint amount that has been sent but how would it know this uint amount is the amount that has been sent already without that somehow being defined?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: 
the value of the uint will only ever change when it is assigned/set some value. It doesn't know anything. `msg.value` is a global variable in Solidity that "knows" what value that the sender sent with the transaction invoking this `payable` function

Comment: So my logic would be that essentially in this example `balanceReceived[msg.sender]` would start with a uint value of 0 and then be incremented by the msg.value which "knows" a certain uint value that the sender had sent?

Comment: yep. that's right

Comment: I understand :) Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`balanceReceived` should be of type `mapping(address => uint)`, and `msg.sender` is of type `address`, `msg.value` is of type `uint`.

So `balanceReceived[msg.sender]` is a uint value but not an address.

Does that make sense?